# How to Eager Load Nested Data?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a one to may relationship between the Entity classes Dataset_Template_TAB and Variable_Template_TAB. Moreover I want to map them to the following DTO class using eager loading.

```
public class TestDataset
{
    public string domainName { get; set; }
    public string structure { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestVariable> variableList { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is to eager load using Linq.

I have the following incomplete,

```
public IQueryable<eService.DTO.TestDataset> getDatasetVariables(string domain)
{
    ISATemplate_schemaEntities isat = new ISATemplate_schemaEntities();

    var domainDatasets = 
        from dds in isat.Dataset_Template_TAB
            .Include(ds => ds.Variable_Template_TAB)
            .ToList()
        select new eTRIKSService.DTO.TestDataset()
        {
            domainDatasetName = dds.domainName,
            structure = dds.structure,
            //How to set TestVariable List
        };

    return domainDatasets;
}
```

My question is how can I set the TestVariable list which is of TestDataset type from Variable_Template_TAB?

Comment: Your `Include` should load the data for the `ds.Variable_Template_TAB` property as well.  Is that the data you're looking for?

Comment: Yes it loads it but how can I set it to the list  (variableList) in my DTO

Comment: Unless I'm missing something it's as simple as `TestVariableList = dds.Variable_Template_TAB`

Comment: I get the following error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<eService.DataAccess.Variable_Template_TAB>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<eService.DTO.TestDataset>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)